# Not able to connect to mongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have installed everything properly but don't know what had happened. This is the code

```
// Connect to MongoDB
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@blogging-site.mantx.mongodb.net/Blogging-site?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
try {
  // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
   mongoose.connect(dbURI,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log(" Mongoose is connected")
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.log("could not connect");
}
```

The error in my VS code treminal is - Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT blogging-site.mantx.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'ETIMEOUT',
syscall: 'queryTxt',
hostname: 'blogging-site.mantx.mongodb.net'
}
I am following net Ninja tutorials and hope i haven't left any step as he instructed.
I had earlier used mongoDB atlas and have mongodb installed in my computer. Does that create any problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem as **'I could connect'** to it.

**I could connect to it**

**Me, someone you don't know, someone who is most probably in the opposite side of the world**

**Someone who could potentially be a person with bad intentions(although I am not).**

It was probably a connection problem(due to bad internet or something) but the bigger problem is

**I could connect to it**

So maybe you would want to leave the MongoDB URI part out before you make it public for everyone to see, unless you want an evil person to steal user-infos, session datas, and what not from your database.

Happy learning!!!

**Edit after the comment**
Here's what you should learn to get started in mongoose:

```
  -setting up initial(also called default) connection with mongoose.connect()
  -configuring schemas with mongoose.Schema()
  -compiling models with schemas with mongoose.model()
  -saving the doc with mongoose.save()
  -querying the database(findOne, find, deleteOne, updateOne, findById are the 
   ones I find most used)
```

And maybe when you get used to all those, you can move to learning populate(you're probably gonna need it in larger projects), creating multiple connections and export schema pattern, validation, middlewares of mongooseJs and many more that I'm sure you'll look into by yourself.

As for the **"can you tell me how had you got connected to the atlas?"**:

I just copied your code and ran in on my computer. Simple as that. That string in dbURI variable is a way to connect to your database atlas. You gave it to me, I used it and connected to it.

Comment: I have changed that username and password but can you tell me how had you got connected to the atlas? I am a new learner and need some help. And thanks for pointing out that part. won't repeat in future

Comment: head over to the mongooseJs docs at https://mongoosejs.com/ and learn few things that are a must. No need to get your head around all things. You won't probably encounter the use of everything anyway, and by the time  you do, I'm sure you'll be experienced enough to understand them.

Comment: @AlokKumar I have updated the answer with what you should learn.

Comment: A lot of thanks for your response. I was able to connect to mongodb atlas in the morning (don't know how), may be you were correct about the network issue but again it is not working now (i checked the network connection ;). the error message is Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT node-tuts.xi19x.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'node-tuts.xi19x.mongodb.net'

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT
```

When the client tried to retrieve the TXT record for `blogging-site.mantx.mongodb.net` from DNS it timed out.

From the same machine, test with nslookup to retrieve the TXT record, if your DNS provider doesn't support that, you will need to use the non-SRV connection string.